# PHP PDO - Bind number of variables dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to add a search feature on my site there are 4 different inputs the user can use although they might not use all 4. I'm appending to my sql query depending on which inputs they fill in;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = 2 ";
if($_GET['ref']){
  $query .= " AND ref = :ref";
}
if($_GET['doors']){
  $query .= " AND doors = :doors";
}
if($_GET['wheels']){
  $query .= " AND wheels = :wheels";
}
if($_GET['location']){
  $query .= " AND location = :location";
}
$query .= ")";

$adverts = Singlequery ($query, array(              
        'ref' => $_GET['ref'],
        'doors' => $_GET['doors'],
        'wheels' => $_GET['wheels'],
        'location' => $_GET['location']
), $conn);
```

This is my query I'm using -

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return $stmt;
}
```

I'm getting the error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I think its expecting all 4 inputs to be used and therefore wants 4 bound variables.

Comment: Yes, you can use other IF (example)

Comment: try to echo `$query` so that you'll know what to expect

Comment: It's a verbose way to generate a query like this, just set the values of the array which used for binding in the `if($_GET ..)` statements too, e.g. `$query .= "AND location ..."; $bind[':location'] = $_GET['location'];` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have a missing parenthesis in your query. You are closing it but not opening.

You should create your variable array also in if clauses as :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = 2 ";
$data=array();
if($_GET['ref']){
  $query .= " AND ref = :ref";
  $data['ref']=$_GET['ref'];
}
if($_GET['doors']){
  $query .= " AND doors = :doors";
  $data['doors']=$_GET['doors'];
}
if($_GET['wheels']){
  $query .= " AND wheels = :wheels";
  $data['wheels']=$_GET['wheels'];
}
if($_GET['location']){
  $query .= " AND location = :location";
  $data['location']=$_GET['location'];
}

$adverts = Singlequery($query, $data, $conn);
```

Comment: Thanks I see what you've done and how you've done it big help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `?` instead the `:alias` format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to say "if this variable is empty, set it to Null" Then the variables that stay empty will be Null instead of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you always feed it an array of size four as to bind, while your query string sometimes won't have as many due to the if statements, hence the error message?